# MS Access SQL, summing a few fields and comparing the value

Tags: sql, ms-access

My table called lets say "table1" looks as follows:

Area | Owner | Numberid | Average

1200 | Fed_G |   998    |    1400

1220  | Priv  |   1001   |    1600

1220 | Local_G |  1001    |   1430

1220 | Prov_G  | 1001     |  1560

1220 | Priv    | 1674     |  1845

1450 | Prov_G  | 1874    |   1982

Ideally what I would like to do is sum a few rows in the average column if:
1. they have the same numberid (lets say three rows all had a numberid=1000 then they would have their average added together)
2.Area=1220

Then take that and append it to the existing table, while setting the Owner field equal to "ALL".

I just started working with Access so I'm not really sure how to do this, this is my horrible attempt:

```
SELECT ind.Area, ind.Owner, ind.numberid, 
(SELECT SUM([Average]) FROM   [table1] 
WHERE [numberid]=ind.numberid) AS Average
FROM [table1] AS ind
WHERE (((ind.numberid)>="1000" And (ind.numberid)<"10000") AND ((ind.Area)="1220"))
```

Can anyone guide me through what I should do? I'm not used to sql syntax.

I tried to use "ind" as a variable to compare to.

So far it gives me column names but no output.

Comment: @HansUp added sample data and gave a description of output. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your desired ouput as well as your table structure. Also Are "Area" and "NumberID" text or integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still unsure whether I understand what you want.  So I'll offer you this query and let you tell us if the result is what you want or how it differs from what you want.

```
SELECT
    t.Area,
    'ALL' AS Owner,
    t.Numberid,
    Sum(t.Average) AS SumOfAverage
FROM table1 AS t
GROUP BY t.Area, 'ALL', t.Numberid;
```

Using your sample data, that query gives me this result set.

```
Area Owner Numberid SumOfAverage
1200 ALL        998         1400
1220 ALL       1001         4590
1220 ALL       1674         1845
1450 ALL       1874         1982
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably I would be able to (maybe) give you a better answer if you improve the wording of your question.

However, to <> you need to select `average` column and [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) `numberid` and `Area` columns. Since the Owner field is <> I guess it doesn't matter in this query that I'm writing:

```
SELECT numberid, area, SUM(average)
FROM table1
WHERE owner = 'your-desired-owner-equal-to-all'
GROUP BY numberid, area
ORDER BY numberid, area
```

Comment: Sorry about that, let me know what I explained wrong. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @fonzy You're welcome. You can put some sample data in your question, and tell us the result of the query based on the sample data.

Comment: I tried to add more information to the question, when I run my query I get column names but no information in the table. Thanks.